# Cant install pandas using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

[Check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Qdv.png)
I'm new to this, but I understand that the file is missing. I'm working in vscode, and the error comes out of vs studio

1

I've been trying to install pandas using pip, but it always fails and gives me a giant wall of error text and this at the bottom

Comment: can I install pandas without vswhere.exe?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77124900/12846804 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/54305638/12846804

Answer (score 0):

reinstall python and try to install pillow pacgage again :pip install pillow

Comment: problem.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
Failed to build pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: can I install pandas without vswhere.exe?

Comment: tring installing wheel first by following cmd: pip install wheel

Comment: go to cmd and type code there

Comment: Yes, I installed wheel, tried pillow again, but the same error

Comment: python3 -m pip install vswhere
Requirement already satisfied: vswhere in c:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.11/site-packages (1.4.0)

If we return to the problem, then I have vswhere, but it doesn’t work, or am I talking about something else

Comment: try this: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow

Comment: did not help(((((((((

Comment: "python3 -m pip install vswhere Requirement already satisfied: " means pillow already installed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).